# Trouble with compressing big data in python

Tags: python, zlib

I have a script in Python to compress big string:

```
import zlib

def processFiles():
  ...
  s = """Large string more than 2Gb"""
  data = zlib.compress(s)
  ...
```

When I run this script, I got a error:

```
ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):#012  File "./../commands/sce.py", line 438, in processFiles#012    data = zlib.compress(s)#012OverflowError: size does not fit in an int
```

Some information:

zlib.**version** = '1.0'

zlib.ZLIB_VERSION = '1.2.7'

```
# python -V
Python 2.7.3

# uname -a
Linux app2 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.54-2 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      65997404    8096588   57900816          0     184260    7212252
-/+ buffers/cache:     700076   65297328
Swap:     35562236          0   35562236

# ldconfig -p | grep python
libpython2.7.so.1.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
libpython2.7.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so
```

How to compress big data (more than 2Gb) in Python?

Comment: Are you on a 64bit version of Python? How much RAM do you have? Python needs to hold the entire string in RAM as well as the compressed object being constructed.

Comment: I have 64Gb RAM, 56Gb is free now. System is Debian 64bit. How to discover that Python is 64bit?

Comment: And your Python version is 64bit, also?

Comment: I update info about system and RAM in topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a RAM issue. Simply either zlib or the python binding cannot handle data larger than 4GB.

Split your data into 4GB (or smaller chunks) and process each one separately.

Comment: Thanks! I wrote a function to compress data by chunks with compressobj, and now it is ok.

Comment: @DmitrySkryabin : please post it.

Answer (score 3):

My function to compress large data:

```
def compressData(self, s):
    compressed = ''
    begin = 0
    blockSize = 1073741824 # 1Gb
    compressor = zlib.compressobj()
    while begin < len(s):
      compressed = compressed + compressor.compress(s[begin:begin + blockSize])
      begin = begin + blockSize
    compressed = compressed + compressor.flush()
    return compressed
```

Answer (score 0):

Try streaming it...

```
import zlib

compressor = zlib.compressobj()
with open('/var/log/syslog') as inputfile:
     data = compressor.compress(inputfile.read())

print data
```

Comment: That solution triggers the same problem as above.

Comment: @user2284570 because the code is faulty. That's not streaming what is done here... But here it is: https://www.adamsmith.haus/python/docs/zlib.compressobj